# Separating command options from strings in a Bash script

Tags: bash, git

I'm looking for a way to write a function calling **git commit** with several messages ; for example :

```
git commit -m "This is the commit headline" -m "This is a new paragraph for the commit" -m "Adding paragraphs makes it easier to give details"
```

Etc.

The thing is, I have trouble finding an efficient way to express in the script what's the option (-m) and what's the string/message.

Here's what I have so far :

```
function commit(){ 
  if [[ $# > 1 ]]
  then
    commit_body=`echo $2 | cut -d '=' -f 2`
    IFS='|' read -r -a paragraphs <<< "$commit_body"
    git commit -m "$1" $(for p in "${paragraphs[@]}"; do echo -n "-m $p"; done)
  else
    git commit -m "$1"
  fi
}
```

The function would be called by executing :

```
commit "Commit headline" body="1st paragraph for the commit|2nd paragraph"
```

The problem is that, in my function, the "-m" argument is considered as a string by the git commit command. But if I take it out of the "echo" string, then it will become an argument of the echo command, which is not what I want.

Do you have any pointers on how to bypass this?

Comment: Is something else generating the arguments for your function? I would probably just use `git commit -F-`, and put my commit message in a here document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function commit() {
        options=("-m" "$1")

        if [[ $# > 1 ]]
        then
                commit_body=`echo "$2" | cut -d '=' -f 2`
                IFS='|' read -r -a paragraphs <<< "$commit_body"
                for msg in "${paragraphs[@]}"
                do
                        options+=("-m" "${msg}")
                done
        fi

        git commit "${options[@]}"
}

commit "Commit headline" body="1st paragraph for the commit|2nd paragraph"
```

```
$ bash -x commit.sh
+ commit 'Commit headline' 'body=1st paragraph for the commit|2nd paragraph'
+ options=("-m" "$1")
+ [[ 2 > 1 ]]
++ echo 'body=1st paragraph for the commit|2nd paragraph'
++ cut -d = -f 2
+ commit_body='1st paragraph for the commit|2nd paragraph'
+ IFS='|'
+ read -r -a paragraphs
+ for msg in "${paragraphs[@]}"
+ options+=("-m" "${msg}")
+ for msg in "${paragraphs[@]}"
+ options+=("-m" "${msg}")
+ git commit -m 'Commit headline' -m '1st paragraph for the commit' -m '2nd paragraph'
```

Comment: One suggestion: `commit_body=${2#*=}`

Comment: I would have done it pretty much like this – you can avoid using `cut` with `IFS='=' read -r _ commit_body <<< "$2"`. Also, you should probably declare all variables as `local`, or they leak into the environment.

Comment: Ah, or what @chepner said for the commit body ;)

Comment: Cut is often the wrong answer, at least if used carelessly: `$ echo 'body=fred=wilma barney=betty' | cut -d = -f 2` ==> `fred`